# What is the equivalent of Tomcat Connector's proxyName and proxyPort configuration in liberty?

Tags: websphere-liberty

At the moment we run a simple Apache reverse proxy to hide our internal hostname from front end users:

```
ProxyPass /webapp https://webserver.internal:443/webapp
ProxyPassReverse /webapp https://webserver.internal:443/webapp
```

On the webserver.internal apache instance, we have:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
  maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
  ...
  proxyName="companysite.com"
  proxyPort="443"
  ...
/>
```

The user would access our webapp via

```
https://companysite.com:443/webapp/abc?wdsl
```

When we are handing URLs back to the user, urls such as:

```
https://webserver.internal:443/webapp/abc.xsd
```

is presented as:

```
https://companysite.com:443/webapp/abc.xsd
```

What would be the equivalent setup under liberty? I wasn't able to find anything relevant in the httpEndPoint property.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere uses private header fields $WSRA and $WSRP to form self-referential URLs (remote address and remote port, respectively).

These are set by WebSphere-aware proxy servers, including the "WAS WebServer Plug-in" that runs in Apache. The vars can also be set manually in generic proxy servers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Liberty documentation for [Using Liberty behind a proxy server](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/forwarded-header.html#_forwarded_and_x_forwarded_headers_and_verification) this is handled using `X-Forwarded-*` headers.

> A proxy or a load balancer can be configured to provide the Forwarded or X-Forwarded-* request headers. WebSphere Liberty will only utilize the Forwarded “for” (the “for” parameter can optionally include the port), “host” and “proto” parameters, or also X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Port, X-Forwarded-Host, and X-Forwarded-Proto headers. Note that the Forwarded “by” parameter or the X-Forwarded-By header is not used.

Apache example for your situation

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
```

`ProxyPreserveHost On` is supplying `X-Forwarded-Host: companysite.com` - an equivalent to `proxyName="companysite.com"`